# Am I doing something wrong or php doesn't support this?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

My problem is that when i try to execute the query below via php's mysql_query function it doesn't do anything(everything work except this query of course). If I put die(mysql_error()) in the end ot the query it only shows white page and not a single error. On the other hand if I try to execute it directly from the mysql client the sql code works. I have no idea what exactly is wrong.
Here's the sql code.

```
-- Instructions:  
-- Set the NPC Entry and stats you want it to have below.  
SET  
@NPC_ENTRY := ".$entry.", -- This is your NPC's Entry  
@NPC_HEALTH := ".$health.", -- This is the health value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_MANA := ".$mana.", -- This is the mana value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_ARMOR := ".$armor."; -- This is the armor value you want your NPC to have.

-- DO NOT CHANGE ANYTHING BELOW, UNLESS YOU KNOW WHAT YOU ARE DOING.  
-- Getting NPC datas:  
SET  
@NPC_CLASS := (SELECT `unit_class` FROM creature_template WHERE Entry = @NPC_ENTRY),  
@NPC_LEVEL := ROUND(((SELECT `minlevel` FROM creature_template WHERE Entry = @NPC_ENTRY)+  (SELECT `maxlevel` FROM creature_template WHERE Entry = @NPC_ENTRY))/2, 0),  
@EXP := (SELECT `exp` FROM creature_template WHERE Entry = @NPC_ENTRY);

-- Getting base HP from a HP column defined by exp.  
SET  
@GET_HP_COL :=  
(SELECT CASE @EXP  
WHEN 0 THEN (SELECT basehp0 FROM creature_classlevelstats WHERE `level` = @NPC_LEVEL and `class` = @NPC_CLASS)  
WHEN 1 THEN (SELECT basehp1 FROM creature_classlevelstats WHERE `level` = @NPC_LEVEL and `class` = @NPC_CLASS)  
WHEN 2 THEN (SELECT basehp2 FROM creature_classlevelstats WHERE `level` = @NPC_LEVEL and `class` = @NPC_CLASS)  
END),  
-- Getting base mana  
@GET_MA_COL := (SELECT basemana FROM creature_classlevelstats WHERE `level` = @NPC_LEVEL and `class` = @NPC_CLASS),  
-- Getting base armor  
@GET_AR_COL := (SELECT basearmor FROM creature_classlevelstats WHERE `level` = @NPC_LEVEL and `class` = @NPC_CLASS);

-- Running the update with all the data collected:  
UPDATE creature_template SET Health_mod = (@NPC_HEALTH/@GET_HP_COL), Mana_mod = (@NPC_MANA/@GET_MA_COL), Armor_mod = (@NPC_ARMOR/@GET_AR_COL) WHERE Entry = @NPC_ENTRY;
```

I apologize if my post have mistakes. English is not my native language. :(

Comment: I think you forgot to add the php part of the code

Comment: You could start and divide this very long query into single lines (within a transaction if you wish). Also, note that **mysql_* functions are deprecated**: use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: as far as i know, php refrains from executing complex multi entries sql queries, this is builtin and you cannot override it, please try to put all this into a stored function, and execute that function from your php code.

Comment: @lbu What php part the query is value of the variable named "statsfix" after that I execute it like that $q2 = mysql_query($statsfix, $world);

Comment: @Gar you mean that i need to convert the whole sql logic into php and update the table with these values?

Comment: if you wish, or just wrap this code into a function (a packaged function) and then call it as a simple single query from your php (select theFunction(params) from dual)

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the problem might be here:

```
SET  
@NPC_ENTRY := ".$entry.", -- This is your NPC's Entry  
@NPC_HEALTH := ".$health.", -- This is the health value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_MANA := ".$mana.", -- This is the mana value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_ARMOR := ".$armor."; -- This is the armor value you want your NPC to have.
```

You posted a single large MySQL query, and I suppose you invoke it with a single call to `mysql_query` (again, **beware of deprecation**). How do you do that?

The SQL should look something like

```
@NPC_ENTRY := 11,  -- This is your NPC's Entry  
@NPC_HEALTH := 42, -- This is the health value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_MANA := 17, -- This is the mana value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_ARMOR := 33; -- This is the armor value you want your NPC to have.
```

and if so, you should do something like this:

```
$query1 = <<<SQL1
SET  
@NPC_ENTRY := {$entry}, -- This is your NPC's Entry  
@NPC_HEALTH := {$health}, -- This is the health value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_MANA := {$mana}, -- This is the mana value you want your NPC to have.  
@NPC_ARMOR := {$armor}; -- This is the armor value you want your NPC to have.
SQL1;

mysql_query($query1);
```

If you just place the query between more quotes, you'll end up with fields like .42. instead of 42, which will break the SQL.

Same goes for comments and multiple queries: some back-ends do not allow that, for various reasons (many believe it's "more secure" to only allow one query at a time, to avoid some classes of SQL attacks).

For these reasons, you might want to split the large query in an array of single SQL statements and execute them one after the other (maybe in a transaction). You can also move comments to PHP:

```
$sqls = array(
    'BEGIN WORK',
    // Set the data
    "SET @NPC_ENTRY := {$entry}," // This is your NPC's Entry
      ."@NPC_HEALTH := {$health},"  // This is the health value you want your NPC to have.  
      ."@NPC_MANA := {$mana},"      // This is the mana value you want your NPC to have.  
      ."@NPC_ARMOR := {$armor};",   // This is the armor value you want your NPC to have.
    // DO NOT TOUCH BELOW THIS
    "SET @NPC_CLASS := ...",
    ...
    "END WORK;"
);

/* Or also like this; it is clearer and almost as efficient.

$sqls = array(
    'BEGIN WORK',
    // Set the data
    "SET @NPC_ENTRY  := {$entry};",   // Your NPC's Entry
    "SET @NPC_HEALTH := {$health};",  // health value you want your NPC to have.  
    "SET @NPC_MANA := {$mana};",      // mana value   " "
    "SET @NPC_ARMOR := {$armor};",    // armor value  " "
    // DO NOT TOUCH BELOW THIS
    "SET @NPC_CLASS := ...;",
    ...
    "END WORK;"
);

*/


unset($error);
foreach($sqls as $sql) {
    if (!mysql_query($sql)) {
        $error = // get MySQL last error
        break;
    }
}
if (isset($error)) {
    ...do something...
}
```

Comment: Actually this is part of variable and the and it starts with " so I end the quotes put the var with the dots and open the string again is that wrong? Also the entry is number not string in the database it's the primary key. And i know that this method is depricated but i can't understand the PDO and mysqli is little stange to me

Comment: I couldn't get this to work so i decided to rewrite the sql calculations into php ones and now it work fine. It even look better. :) tnx anyway